# how to save extensive information from news or programming articles without json issuing an error message?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have seen an infinity of similar questions giving to choose options without a precise answer.

I have a forum with various information, extensive news where the text is combined with html code given to the text editor that replaces the `textarea`, apart from news I can also write questions or tutorials with programming code.

Now the question is that I should select to store large amount content `longtext`, `mediumtext` or others

I am currently using `longtext`, but this gives me an error when querying json data

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes)
```

I have the following code that generates data in json php:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
                                id_news,
                                url,
                                cover_page,
                                alt_img,
                                mini_title,
                                mini_description,
                                date_post,
                                datail,
                                confg_img,
                                main_cover
                            FROM news ORDER BY id_news DESC LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->execute();
        $member = array();
        $stmt->bind_result(
            $member['id_news_sport'],
            $member['url'],
            $member['cover_page'],
            $member['alt_img'],
            $member['mini_title'],
            $member['mini_description'],
            $member['date_post'],
            $member['detail'],
            $member['confg_img'],
            $member['main_cover']
        );

        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo '[';
        $count = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if( $count ) {
                echo ',';
            }

            echo json_encode($member, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

            ++$count;
        }

        echo ']';
 ?>
```

Comment: How do you use PHP to process the data ? Please share your codes

Comment: Indeed, show the code for storing and retrieving the data.

Comment: @WesleySmith Ready friend, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Hmm, I see you have a limit of 5 on there already, just how big is the data stored in each row?

Comment: @WesleySmith Well friend, as I said, they can be very extensive given that the * detail * column is where the complete detail of a news item is stored and, as you can understand, sometimes the news is extensive in addition to adding a block or YouTube embed code. , twitter and others. Besides, it can also be a programming article where in the same way it will be extensive given the code and the step-by-step documentation of how each line works.

Comment: Can you try the suggestions listed here? https://www.airpair.com/php/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size